# Manipulate data to match given mean and standard deviation

Tags: statistics, transformation, standard-deviation, means

I have a set of data with a mean of $55.05$ and a standard deviation of $7.51$. However, I want to transform these data to a list of values with a mean of $55.62$, a standard deviation of $58.69$ and the list should not contain negative values.

Is this possible?

Thank you

The list of data is below:

```
63,25343492
58,46647552
70,1893707
62,02920512
46,81912721
38,62651421
54,91834215
53,5648866
66,58933926
53,44316012
66,35574684
61,4587485
39,3649
45,85913993
48,00987736
70,02203183
55,09231297
53,05058226
61,80686162
70,89394706
48,53529541
64,26565334
47,80300402
59,23700534
51,88877063
38,69512242
64,4900316
49,49378877
60,15633028
55,56446765
63,18853348
59,33611195
70,10515712
48,17858153
57,68142533
51,03872336
69,40552751
53,59097579
52,80740962
52,30157743
56,08804551
53,03329499
52,04072179
53,5688407
63,04249864
52,93057395
43,13632994
52,36371528
55,35402605
57,1120537
60,48213353
48,71669955
58,83728766
53,12609614
53,03303446
47,03379664
50,20478272
52,80171426
51,55706095
56,0172937
46,56791444
38,96889239
53,14244022
60,06590358
65,1300528
73,4724206
57,4408382
55,85660987
52,4207217
61,09611171
53,45293161
55,1140787
55,88977952
52,99888866
63,57548193
59,21058636
52,28955351
70,71567257
51,58985465
64,5838287
49,87066563
47,25890702
47,0767081
54,10798435
55,77987579
52,29006138
63,52081038
59,82786897
43,32256542
53,84019996
49,43879073
65,83450715
55,11900566
48,51611519
69,89401638
50,46511071
60,63654817
52,64315423
57,37887843
27,69265302
49,14289887
58,8887636
70,6123843
66,95574219
56,98665343
69,66994482
60,10217979
55,68536966
49,31678724
52,80025991
42,7260427
46,77761073
54,01579331
49,40364238
48,09137352
41,42521403
56,78384303
42,94948767
49,61580545
54,78690354
40,84314573
55,89356544
58,5912459
58,81514928
39,70456407
58,04789421
60,29536381
52,16125774
55,26669272
63,04562829
55,28027981
57,46656792
53,70214918
58,79549087
59,46990521
55,31339009
58,37461096
64,63075033
47,02739224
56,73003551
42,36365324
50,83343298
55,69348894
69,6040837
62,24566527
53,64166025
51,24845592
42,27381025
64,40506612
63,25815082
56,24299769
68,70028498
52,93784239
54,43262017
52,98691751
49,02647202
50,66430009
37,10591106
58,28431947
44,79790575
54,94091585
64,1397584
64,62166149
62,7770689
55,50020929
60,43260991
47,68335848
60,85639191
63,27062325
56,9093851
60,4381041
53,08066183
42,87721556
46,75362556
56,52171112
57,12483612
47,79726248
54,09436429
61,1144147
56,753991
46,52390151
54,0095505
57,58468327
46,85270249
69,23396741
65,02744389
53,75206855
54,63300996
60,5300577
43,98179652
51,65379312
43,36955301
62,92077546
50,92264608
58,52230791
53,47326278
54,482589
43,88931527
53,98827615
53,55388171
59,34192933
51,1088057
50,20534665
36,42917504
61,57306474
53,4040016
44,6422808
65,68931656
56,36393928
46,19969771
54,67038106
58,72142474
55,37179809
52,14944159
53,73874199
60,47480244
56,52727128
40,94344286
63,44741701
63,49801903
58,94707596
52,26117562
43,90568903
59,71872045
60,50918239
62,48497944
58,69732414
59,16129688
53,42235077
62,30943885
54,61844341
61,54267517
59,26788629
50,10868374
64,08723045
52,65740089
66,01882658
49,48888488
50,78264958
64,4557242
54,47369803
50,40597059
42,45460429
53,63955293
49,3218758
49,61972988
57,22906427
55,60043386
55,07462007
55,92224343
```

Comment: It depends. What is the approximate distribution of your data set?

Comment: Transform the data $z_i=a+bx_i$ and choose $a$ and $b$ to give you your desired mean and variance.

Comment: @Sean Roberston. I added the data to check.  Thanks

Comment: @user121049. Can you give an example as to how you would treat my data? Thanks

Comment: If you want the SD greater than the mean _and_ if you want all positive values, the the distribution may have to be much more strongly right-skewed (long tail trailing to the right) than a normal distribution. For nearly normal data there is a rule of thumb that about 95% of the observations lie within two standard deviations on either side of the mean. And there may be 'stragglers' beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment continued.** To illustrate the difficulty mentioned in my comment above:
Below is a histogram of roughly normally
distributed data (close to symmetrical about their mean anyhow) with sample mean $\bar X = 58.68$ and sample
standard deviation $S = 55.62.$ A major portion of them is negative.

[image]

*Note:* I tried dealing with your data, first changing all the commas (,) to
periods (.) so software configured to American conventions can handle them.
But I got mean 55.483 and SD 6.026.